# How to calculate dynamically a column containing a formula in SQL Server a return the value

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, replace, formula

I've been searching for this but I dont know how to ask for this specific information.

Lets imagine I have something like this in  my sql table.

```
Columns:
width : 10
height: 15
Depth: 6
```

And I have a formula column like this

```
formula: (W*2)+H+D+3
```

where I replace W with Width, H with Height, and D with depth.
using sql Replace, I am able to do this and convert the final result as

```
(10*2)+15+6+3
```

The problem is that I need the calculation to be done in the column as a result.

I tried this direcly in SQL

```
select 1 as width , 
2 as height , 
3 as depth , 
'H*2+W' as formula,
replace(Replace(REPLACE('H*2+W','W',1),'H',2),'D',3) as result
```

I need to be able to do this directly in the query, and calculate each row result with its specific value.

I tried doing Execs inside Select, but no luck. this would run 1000 querys if my initial query has 1000 rows...

How can I make this the best possible way?

Comment: Create UDF. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score -1):

You can't easily do what you want.  SQL Server does not have a convenient parsing mechanism for creating code from strings. You could use dynamic SQL and a cursor, but that is cumbersome.

However, you may be able to store your formulas using coefficents:

```
formula         w_coeff    h_coeff    d_coeff    constant
(W*2)+H+D+3        2          1           1          3
'H*2+W'            1          2           0          0
```

Then you can do:

```
select v.*, f.*,
       (f.w_coeff * v.w + f.h_coeff * v.h + f.d_coeff * v.d + f.constant)
from (values (1, 2, 3)) v(w, h, d) cross join
     formulas f;
```